# IAM auth for ClusterClient using go-redis

Tags: authentication, redis, amazon-elasticache, identity-management, go-redis

I am using go-redis package to interface with AWS elasticache for Redis using `redis.NewClusterClient`. I am authenticating into the redis instance like so,

```
import "github.com/go-redis/redis/v8"

func InitRedis() {
    RedisClient := redis.NewClusterClient(redis.ClusterOptions{
        Addrs:     []string{"redis-address"},
        Password:  "redis-password",
        PoolSize:  10,
    })

    _, err := RedisClient.Ping().Result()
    if err != nil {
        log.Error(err, "could not establish connection")
        return
    }
}
```

With the recent addition of [support for IAM auth](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/11/amazon-elasticache-supports-iam-authentication-redis-clusters/) for redis clusters, I'm looking to move away from the password usage and migrate to using IAM auth. I saw [this example](https://github.com/redis/go-redis/discussions/2343) on authenticating using `CredentialsProvider` for a redis `Client`. However, I cannot see how I can do the same for a `ClusterClient` since the [ClusterOptions struct](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-redis/redis/v9#ClusterOptions) does not seem to have support for `CredentialsProvider`. How should I go about authenticating into elasticache redis using IAM for a ClusterClient with the go-redis package?

Referred to https://github.com/redis/go-redis/discussions/2343, https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/auth-iam.html

Comment: Could we do something like here - https://noise.getoto.net/author/younggu-yun/ (Search for `CredentialsProvider` on the page)